# numpy all() evaluating incorrectly

Tags: python, numpy

My code should stop when all the values of my array are greater than 100. I am using np.all() to evaluate the condition. It looks like the condition is met, but np.all() seems to be incorrectly evaluating. What am I missing? Python 2.7.8 on OS 10.8.5.

```
(Pdb) ratio_J_a
array([ 250.44244741,  186.92848637,  202.67726408,  143.01112845,
        132.95878384,  176.49130164,  178.9892571 ,  118.07516559,
        205.59639112,  183.64142204])
(Pdb) np.all(ratio_J_a) > 100.
False 
(Pdb) np.all(ratio_J_a) < 100.
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) tests whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to True.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ratio_J_a = np.array([
...     250.44244741,  186.92848637,  202.67726408,  143.01112845,
...     132.95878384,  176.49130164,  178.9892571 ,  118.07516559,
...     205.59639112,  183.64142204
... ])
>>> np.all(ratio_J_a > 100)
True
>>> np.all(ratio_J_a < 100)
False
```

### Why you got wrong result:

`np.all(ratio_J_a)` is evaluated as `True` because non-zero numbers are treated as a truth value. And `True` is equal to 1. `1 > 100` is False, `1 < 100` is True.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have:

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: ratio_J_a = np.array([ 250.44244741,  186.92848637,  202.67726408,  143.01112845,
   ...:                 132.95878384,  176.49130164,  178.9892571 ,  118.07516559,
   ...:                     205.59639112,  183.64142204])

In [7]: print(np.all(ratio_J_a > 100.))
True

In [8]: print(np.all(ratio_J_a < 100.))
False
```

And just in case, you are actually wondering why you got this:

```
(Pdb) np.all(ratio_J_a) > 100.
False 
(Pdb) np.all(ratio_J_a) < 100.
True
```

The reason is that `np.all(ratio_J_a)` evaluates to true, which is treated as one, e.g.

```
In [17]: "{}".format(np.all(ratio_J_a))
Out[17]: 'True'

In [18]: "{:d}".format(np.all(ratio_J_a))
Out[18]: '1'
```

Thus, in your case you are actually doing this:

```
(Pdb) 1 > 100.
False 
(Pdb) 1 < 100.
True
```

Comment: This doesn't address why all values > 100 evaluates to false.

Comment: For me it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I think the OP would be more enlightened if they saw that the result of `ratio_J_a < 100.` and `ratio_J_a > 100.` was a boolean array.